# Redirect rule in UrlRewrite module not working as expected IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, url-rewrite-module

the need is to redirect every non www hit to www urls and for doing that i have following rule

```
<rule name="WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

what is does right now- it redirects every hit of non www url to my home page (www.domain.com)
Expected- it should redirect domain.com/subpage to www.domain.com/subpage

Comment: are you using ssl for your website?

Comment: no we are not using ssl

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,it's work for me

```
<rule name="www" >
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with my New HAProxy LB cluster which was doing some sort of redirection with its own, redirect rule is fine. fixed it with the help of IT